# $0$-dimensional manifold

Tags: proof-writing, manifolds

Denote $\mathbb{R}^0=\{0\}$.

> **Proposition.** A topological space $M$ is a $0$-manifold if and only if it is a countable discrete space.

**Proof.** $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose that $M$ be a topological manifold of dimension $0$. Let $p\in M$ and let $p\in U$ be a ngb of $p$ homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^0$. Since the only open subset of $\mathbb{R}^0$ is $\mathbb{R}^0$ itself, $U$ must contain one element, so $U=\{p\}$. Therefore, every one-point subset of $M$ is open, so $M$ is a discrete space.

> **Question 1.** Is true or false that every second-countable space is countable? If yes, why?

If the answer at the question 1 is yes, then $M$ is a countable discrete space.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that $M$ be a countable discrete space, we must prove that $M$ is Hausdorff, second-countable and locally Eulidean.

> **Question 2.** How can I proceed to prove this implication?

Thanks!

Comment: What about a second-countable discrete space?

Comment: If M is countable discrete space. Start with showing how it can be a 0-Manifold? Can you find neighborhood homeomorphic to a 0-dimensional Euclidean space?

Comment: I know that if a space is countable and discrete, then is second countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false that every second countable space is countable. Second countable means that there exists some countable base $\mathcal{B}$. $\mathbb{R}$ is second countable since a countable number of intervals is a base for $\mathbb{R}$, but it's clearly not countable.

For the forward direction, in your case, since (by definition) $M$ is second countable, and each $U = \{p\}$ is open, and each open set is a union of sets from the basis $\mathcal{B}$, we have that $U \in \mathcal{B}$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is countable, so is $M$, since $M = \bigcup \mathcal{B}$.

For the backward direction, we have:
$M$ is

- Hausdorff - consider any two $p,q$ in $M$. Use discreteness of $M$ to conclude immediately.
- Second countable (since it's countable)
- Locally euclidean. Fix a $p \in M$. Map $p \mapsto 0$ from $U = \{p\} $ to $\{0\}$. Continuous, bijective with countinous inverse.

Comment: @JuliusL33tthanks for your answer but when you say: "Since $\mathcal{B}$ is countable, so is $M$, since $M=\bigcup\mathcal{B}$" there is an error, since even $\mathbb{R}$ admits a countable basis but it is not countable.

Comment: I concluded by saying that since $M$ is second-countable and discrete, then it is countable.

Comment: Just because $\mathcal{B}$ is countable does not mean that $M$ is countable, just like you say. What I meant is that: if $\{p\} \in \mathcal{B} $ for every $p \in M$ AND $\mathcal{B}$ is countable, then $M$ is also countable. So yes, absolutely, if $M$ is second countable and discrete, then $M$ is countable.